# htaccess rewrite any folder but not any file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have URLs like these pointing at folders:

```
1) https://try.com/documentation/license/
2) https://try.com/documentation/license
```

I want to rewrite both pointing at PHP/pages.php

I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ PHP/pages.php [NC]
```

This works in case #1 but not in case #2.

I have also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule PHP/pages.php [L]
```

This does not work at all.

The case is that the directory name is this:

```
/pages/documentation/license/
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your .htaccess file into your pages directory/folder and place following rules in it. Also please clear your cache of your browser before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^documentation/license/?$ PHP/pages.php [NC,L]
```

For Generic rewrite: you could use following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ PHP/pages.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a generic solution.

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm, which kind of? You mean any URI eg--> `http://localhost:80/abc/def/` TO `http://localhost:80/PHP/pages.php` should rewrite like that? Kindly confirm once and I will edit my answer then.

Comment: It works even it matches almost anything. If possible to actually test if the directory exists, then it would be better.

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm, sure, I have changed the solution, added condition which will check if directory is present then only it will move further, let me know if this works for you, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I do really appreciate it. However, it does not work for me. The case is that the actual directory exists but at a different path. See above.

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm, could you please give me example(samples only) here, will try to edit solution accordingly then, cheers.

Comment: The examples are actually in my question above. The request is this: /documentation/license/ but the actually file path is: /pages/documentation/license/

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm, oh ok, for that I had already posted place your .htaccess file into your pages directory and try once?

Comment: Sorry, but I have tested it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm, ok could you please try to set `Rewritebase /pages` after `RewriteEngine ON` line and clear your cache and try again and let me know please how it goes.

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm, Sorry trying my best to help here. One more try. How about keeping htaccess file in your root, then your root will have like `.htaccess, pages` in same folder. Along with `RewriteBase pages` sorry I don't have that setup couldn't test it, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: I cannot get it work. My idea is to add 'pages' into the RewriteCond but basically don't know how to do this? Anyway, thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm, I am still not leaving it, trying to test it in my local machine, will post here if I get something, cheers.